# How to Create Jetty Spring App With HBase Connection

Tags: java, spring, hbase, embedded-jetty, onejar

I am creating a Spring app with Embedded jetty in a single jar package using the [OneJar Maven Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/).  It is meant to be an api that service requests backed backed by Apache Hbase.  It compiles fines but when I run it:

```
$ java -jar target/myapp.one-jar.jar
JarClassLoader: Warning: Null manifest from input stream associated with: lib/javax.inject-1.jar
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap.class in lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar is hidden by lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack.class in lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar is hidden by lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$Values.class in lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar is hidden by lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$CollectionView$CollectionViewIterator.class in lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar is hidden by lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$1.class in lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar is hidden by lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/BufferUnderflowException.class in lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar is hidden by lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$KeySet.class in lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar is hidden by lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$CollectionView.class in lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar is hidden by lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$EntrySet.class in lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar is hidden by lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/beanutils/BasicDynaBean.class in lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar is hidden by lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/beanutils/BasicDynaClass.class in lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar is hidden by lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar (with different bytecode)
```

And then, as the Spring context is initializing I get this stack trace

```
13/09/08 18:57:06 ERROR context.ContextLoader: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hConnection' defined in class com.example.myapp.context.Config: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnection com.example.myapp.context.Config.hConnection() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1025)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:921)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
```

Are these two related?  How do I fix this?  Here is my construction of the hConnection bean:

```
@Bean
@Named("hConnection")
public HConnection hConnection() throws Exception {
    org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration configuration = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
    HConnection hConnection = HConnectionManager.createConnection(configuration);
    HTableInterface hTableInterface = hConnection.getTable("mytable");
    hTableInterface.close();
    return hConnection;
}
```

I have to use the fully qualified package name for Hadoop Configuration because it conflicts with the `org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration` annotation.

The associated unit test for the HConnection passes with `mvn test`:

```
public class HConnectionTest {

    @Test
    public void testHConnection() throws Exception {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        HConnection hConnection = HConnectionManager.createConnection(configuration);
        Assert.assertEquals(hConnection.getClass().getSimpleName(),"HConnectionImplementation");

        HTableInterface hTableInterface = hConnection.getTable("__test__");

        Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("__test__"));
        put.add(Bytes.toBytes("source"), Bytes.toBytes("__test__"),Bytes.toBytes("__test__"));

        hTableInterface.put(put);

        Get get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("__test__"));
        Result result = hTableInterface.get(get);

        byte [] value = result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("source"), Bytes.toBytes("__test__"));
        String valueStr = Bytes.toString(value);
        Assert.assertEquals(valueStr, "__test__");
    }
}
```

It also seems to me that the `JarClassLoader` warnings have something to do with it.  I wonder if I should exclude certain packages?  By the way, this is

```
Hadoop 1.2.1
Hbase 0.94.11
Java 1.7.0_25
Mac OS X 10.8.4
```

Update:  The issue still persists, but it also incidently turned out I had the wrong version of Apache cxf.  I needed 2.7.2, but had 2.7.5.  I tried moving my HBase Connection instantiation to its own class, not the Spring Annotation config.  This helped the situation in the sense that I can now run my app and ping the health check, but I still cannot connect to HBase.  When I request a URL that uses my HBase Connection I get the following stack trace:

```
2013-09-09 03:05:52,476 WARN [||] [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (qtp2108992104-28:) - Application {http://api.myapp.example.com/}HealthCheck has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not initialize class com.example.myapp.service.HbaseSubmissionService
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162) ~[cxf-api-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128) ~[cxf-api-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:102) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58) ~[cxf-api-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94) ~[cxf-api-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271) ~[cxf-api-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[cxf-api-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:218) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:163) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:137) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:158) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:243) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:168) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735) ~[javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:219) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1094) ~[jetty-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1028) ~[jetty-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136) ~[jetty-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) ~[jetty-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445) ~[jetty-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:267) ~[jetty-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:224) ~[jetty-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358) ~[jetty-io-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601) ~[jetty-util-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532) ~[jetty-util-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
```

... some stack trace omitted for SO length limitations

The one part of the error that doesn't quite make sense to me is this:

```
13/09/09 03:29:55 FATAL conf.Configuration: error parsing conf file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /target/myapp.one-jar.jar (No such file or directory)
```

I haven't yet understood what code or package is trying to parse the actual jar?  What does that mean?  I think this might be Hadoop looking for its configuration files on the classpath, but my classpath includes

```
~/Hadoop/lib//hadoop/conf:~/Hadoop/lib/hbase/conf
```

which is where I keep my Hadoop and Hbase config files. The part that seems like the culprit is the initialization of my HBaseConnection class:

```
Could not initialize class com.example.myapp.service.HbaseSubmissionService
```

Update:  Here is the result of `mvn dependency:tree`

```
[INFO] com.example.myapp:jar:0.1.0
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.1.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0-m10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.13:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.0.4.v20130625:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:jar:3.0.0.v201112011016:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.0.4.v20130625:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.0.4.v20130625:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.0.4.v20130625:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.0.4.v20130625:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.0.4.v20130625:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.0.4.v20130625:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.0.4.v20130625:compile
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:0.94.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.stephenc.high-scale-lib:high-scale-lib:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.netty:netty:jar:3.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.thrift:libthrift:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jruby:jruby-complete:jar:1.6.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-2.1:jar:6.1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-api-2.1:jar:6.1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api-2.5:jar:6.1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jamon:jamon-runtime:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.4.0a:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO]    +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO]    +- tomcat:jasper-runtime:jar:5.5.23:compile
[INFO]    +- tomcat:jasper-compiler:jar:5.5.23:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.6.1:compile
[INFO]    +- hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.10:compile
[INFO]    +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO]    \- org.eclipse.jdt:core:jar:3.1.1:compile
```

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace. One thing to notice is that you have (possible) conflicting jars (commons-beanutils 1.7 and 1.8). You might want to figure out your dependencies and use the most recent 1.8.3 version of beanutils-core and exclude all other dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I added beanutils 1.8.3, how do I figure out what artifacts are including the other versions so I can exclude them?  I also have other JarClassLoader errors, such as 1JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/servlet/Filter.class in lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar is hidden by lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar (with different bytecode)` and `JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/jasper/JspC.class in lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar is hidden by lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar (with different bytecode)`

Comment: and `JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/ws/rs/Path.class in lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar is hidden by lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar (with different bytecode)`.  I think to your point there are some conflicting jars being brought in by either hadoop or hbase.

Comment: and `JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate$HeaderDelegate.class in lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar is hidden by lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class in lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar is hidden by lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar (with different bytecode)`  Seems like there are a few major conflicting jars.

Comment: Use `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out your dependencies. Optionally configure/add the maven [enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) with a [dependency convergence](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html) rule. That will break the build if multiple versions of the same dependency are found.

Comment: Is it possible there is no solution?  Ie Hadoop or Hbase requires some version of some class, but my Jetty app requires another?  I ran `mvn dependency:tree`.  Are you free to take this into a private chat to talk more about exclusions etc?  Would be grateful for more help!

Comment: Is there a way to tell Maven I only want one class from a dependency, and to only pull in the minimal needed classes?  For example from Hadoop all I am calling in my code is `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration`

Comment: Not AFAIK. You might be able to configure the OneJAR plugin that way, but I know to little of it.

Comment: So how can I interpret the `mvn dependency:tree` output?  Particularly, is there a strategy to resolving the conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can specifically slice out the web server components of hbase to surpress these errors with the following XML monstrosity.  Whether or not this causes the application to "work" is a different matter.  Working with this solution for a few hours, its clear this is not the end of the story.  But does resolve the class collisions.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.4.v20130625</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.4.v20130625</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
        <version>0.94.11</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api-2.5</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api-2.5</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasper-compiler</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasper-runtime</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
                <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasper-compiler</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasper-runtime</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```